# run 7zip as process with progress indictation

Tags: c#, .net, progress, 7zip

I'm running 7zip as a process from my c# application.

I'm reading the output, but i can't get percentage of the operation only completion

```
        _loadedProcess.OutputDataReceived += _loadedProcess_OutputDataReceived;

        _loadedProcess.ErrorDataReceived += _loadedProcess_ErrorDataReceived;

        _loadedProcess.Start();

        _loadedProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        _loadedProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Its crucial that i'll have a progress bar in my application (and not the  7zG progress bar) 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use a compatible compression library or wrapper such as http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/?

Comment: I tried to use it but it couldn't compress huge folders. I got an exception and the log said there is a bug in sevenzipsharp. The same folder is compressed when using 7zip.exe

Comment: If there's a bug in that (I have no experience with it, I'm assuming it's relatively stable, but perhaps not perfect), you'll probably have an easier time solving that bug, than you'll have properly parsing the output of the command-line tool. Parsing stdout of random programs whose output is not designed to be machine-readable is very difficult to get right.